# Java У меня есть массив в другом классе, и мне нужно изменять данные в нем, но этого не происходит

Tags: java, массивы

Java У меня есть массив в другом классе, и мне нужно изменять данные в нем, но этого не происходит, и каждый раз, когда я хочу добавить новые числа через main класс массив обнуляется. Помогите, что с этим делать?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int h1 = scanner.nextInt();
            int h2 = scanner.nextInt();
            Mone mone = new Mone();
            mone.a[h1] += h2;
            mone.b();
        }
    }
}

public class Mone {
   public int[] a = {0,0,0,0,0};
   public void b(){
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           System.out.println(a[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mone mone = new Mone();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        int h1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int h2 = scanner.nextInt();
        mone.a[h1] += h2;
        mone.b();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Mone mone = new Mone();
    while(true) {
      ...
      //Mone mone = new Mone();
      ...
    }
```